# Managing Backups: Space Issues

Tags: backup

I recently reached 95% full storage on my GMail. Approximately 60% of this was, in fact, email backups from Wordpress' "WP-DB-Backup" plugin on 10+ sites that I manage. (I get a scheduled daily backup of the whole database.)

There must be a better way to manage my backups. Ideally, if I can somehow automatically delete all but the most recent backup (whatever the solution is), that would be best. Sure, I can manually do this in GMail, but it's tedious and error-prone.

Is there a better way to do this, or a better way to manage WP backups without worrying about HD space? GMail doesn't look like it's a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a plugin like [**`backwpup`**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/backwpup/) that lets you:

- Store backup to Folder
- Store backup to FTP Server
- Store backup to Amazon S3
- Store backup to Google Storage
- Store backup to Microsoft Azure (Blob)
- Store backup to RackSpaceCloud
- Store backup to DropBox **(free)**
- Store backup to SugarSync **(free)**

and manage the number of backup copies to store which means for example you set the number to be 5 and when you reach backup number 6 the first back will be deleted for you.